# Black and Decker drill just started to lose power in clockwise direction. What could be worn off?

Tags: drill

It is an [800w corded drill](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Black-Decker-800W-Hammer-Drill/dp/B009TPTO18) and was working just fine till recently. Counter clockwise mode works full power but the clockwise mode is completely useless, drill starts at some decent speed and power(about 80-90% that of counter clockwise) but stops on the slightest contact or sometimes even before contact with anything and won't start until i switch the direction back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the list of what's not broken: the clutch, because your drill doesn't have one. The gear is not likely to be broken either because transmission reversal is simply done on the commutator level on a drill like this, with a switch that swaps the brushes.

[image]

(Image from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167556/how-does-the-circuit-of-a-basic-variable-speed-electric-drill-work)).

The switch that does the reversal may have a damaged or loose contact for one direction but not the other. It's also possible you have a broken brush and the remaining bit is pushed away by the rotor in one direction but not the other. Less likely is a dislodged brush holder that does the same thing. If the drill is out of warranty, open it. (I don't know if the B&D warranty requires you *not* to open it.) If nothing looks wrong with brushes or their holders, I'd suspect the reversal switch. It may not be easiest thing to debug if it fails only under vibration; you could however temporarily bypass it with a direct connection and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Turns out you were on the right track. I opened it up and it seems like a poor design by black and decker, the trigger basically slips off the contact that it pushes against when in the clockwise direction, but has a better contact in the anticlockwise direction. Nothing seemed broken or worn or loose.

Answer (score 2):

Not a switch problem, as it energizes both forward and reverse.

Not a battery/power problem because you have full power in one of the directions.

I would suspect that you busted an internal gear.

Comment: Or burned/worn brushes, etc.

Comment: I would go with brushes before gears , check the brushes before using or you might destroy the commentator pads.

Answer (score -4):

Common problem, here it is in this pic, on the right side of the UL label.

[image]

Comment: Com'on man, people are looking for real answers. . .

Comment: And I just gave one. It's not an opinion, it's fact.